How to select the closest point to another point based on the value of an attribute?
I have a stream layer.
I created a layer of cross sections on the watercourses (CF).
I extract the cross-section and watercourse intersection point layer (I).
I add altitude z to layer I and z+5 to layer CF.
when the layers are small, I use a nearest function from a Qgis inRefunction plug to select the IDs of the CF layer which has a z+5 > z of layer I. This function is very slow when the files are large.
I want to select the points of the CF layer which have the z+10 the
when there are not many points
Does anyone have an idea?


I don't see any table definition(s) (CREATE TABLE statement(s)), Postgres version, sample data, existing indexes, the query you tried - or anything related to Postgres at all. Is PostGIS installed, too?
